# Uninstalling/deleting Calligra

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, delete, trash, ebooks

I am installed Calligra on Ubuntu 12.04, but I do not like it and now I want to uninstall it. I am installed unstable release with project-neon. I am tried to delete folder in /opt but I can not permanetly delete it. How to uninstall/delete Calligra and Project Neon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get purge calligra
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Depending on how you installed Project Neon, you would:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:neon/ppa/ 

sudo apt-get purge project-neon-kdeplasma-addons project-neon-session
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get purge project-neon-kdepim project-neon-common
```

Or as Beni Bogosel said you can use synaptic.

Comment: @legospace9876 It was nothing, you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Try using one of the software package managers Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center. Open, for example, Ubuntu Software Manager, search for Calligra and press the remove button.